# Using port 80 for non http

Tags: sockets, port

Is it possible to use port 80 for non http traffic ? For example I'm making a small script that will communicate with a friends computer through the internet, however they must port forward it to get past the router. Is there a problem with using port 80 in the script so it will be let through automatically ? Is there some part of this i don't understand that will not let non http data through ? Please explain :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is no problem doing that. in fact, skype's default behaviour is to use port 80 and port 443 to transport voice!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ISPs that actually block port 80, so you might want to try a different port if you are having a problem (still needs to be forwarded)

The firewall on the computer also needs to be set to allow the incoming traffic.

Answer (score 0):

This will work fine, but your friend may still need to setup port forwarding

If your friend's PC is the one listening on Port 80, he will need to setup port forwarding.  Otherwise, how would the router/NAT know which computer in the house to bridge the connection to?

But if your friend's PC is the one making the outbound connection, then likely no port forwarding is needed at all on his end.

In other words, port forwarding (for TCP) is only for inbound connections.  The router/NAT will automatically setup a port mapping scheme for outbound connections (as it does it with all web traffic).